# Orthogonal Trajectory for $y=e^{cx}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this homework question, and while I feel pretty comfortable with the topic, the answer I got is pretty messy so I'm not sure if I made a mistake somewhere. I have the equation for which I need to find the orthogonal trajectory:
$$
  y=e^{cx} \tag{a}
$$

Taking the partial derivative with respect to $x$, I get

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=ce^{cx} \tag{b}$$

From (a), we can solve for $c$ by taking the natural log of each side, yielding

$$c=\frac{\ln(y)}{x}   \tag{c}$$

Substituting into (b), we get

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\ln(y)}{x}e^{cx} \tag{d}$$

To find the family of curves that would intersect orthogonal to (d), we take the negative reciprocal of (d), yielding:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{e^{cx}\ln(y)} \tag{e}$$$

Solving via separation of variables, we get

$$\int\,\ln(y)\; dy = \int\,-xe^{-cx}\;dx \tag{f}$$

This is where I feel I might have made a mistake. Maybe I should have solved via an integrating factor? Anyway, the way I proceeded was to use integration by parts on both sides.

Integrating $\ln(y)$ yields

$$y[\ln(y)-1]+k$$

Integrating $-xe^{-cx}$ yields

$$-\frac{xe^{-cx}}{c}-\frac{1}{c^2}e^{-cx}$$

Finally giving an integral curve

$$y[\ln(y)-1]+k=-\frac{xe^{-cx}}{c}-\frac{1}{c^2}e^{-cx}$$

Can someone let me know if/where I made a mistake? I'm not even necessarily sure it is wrong, and I feel like I generally know what I'm doing, but its just kind of a weird problem. Thanks

Comment: Try instead
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=cy$$
The DE for your trajectory, then, is
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=-\frac{1}{cy}$$
Separation of variables should give you a very simple answer

Comment: But how would that be correct? If you are taking the derivative with respect to x, then you would still have the e^cx in there. If you took it with respect to y, the e^cx would go away but so would the y because the derivative of y would be 1. So then it would be

dx/dy= c

Wouldn't it? How did you get rid of the exponential?

Comment: Observe that $y=e^{cx}$, so I took the derivative with respect to $x$,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=ce^{cx}$$and then substituted in $y=e^{cx}$ giving the desired $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=cy$$

Comment: But the whole point is to eliminate C so that doesn't work :(

Comment: What, no? You don't want to (can't in fact) eliminate $c$. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The line $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1}{cy}$ in nathan.j.mcdougall's answer is incorrect; a solution to this equation (in which $c$ is arbitrary but *fixed*) will be orthogonal to $y = e^{cx}$ for this fixed value of $c,$ but not to every member of the family $y = e^{cx},$ which is what is required of an orthogonal trajectory.

The OP is correct to argue (in the comments) that $c$ must be eliminated -- we wish to find an equation satisfied by *every* member of the family. In the same spirit, however, we should write equation (d) as $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\ln{y}}{x}y = \frac{y\ln{y}}{x},$ which is true for every member of the original family, rather than substituting $y = e^{cx},$ which is only true for the one member corresponding to this fixed (albeit arbitrary) value of $c.$ Thus, the orthogonal trajectories satisfy $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x}{y\ln{y}},$ which we solve by separation of variables, as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}y=e^{cx}\\
\implies \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=ce^{cx}\end{align}\\
\implies \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=cy$$
Giving a differential equation for the orthogonal trajectory as:
$$\begin{align} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=-\frac{1}{cy}\\
\implies \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}y=-\frac{1}{c}\\
\implies \int\,y\;\mathrm{d}y=\int\,-\frac{1}{c}\;\mathrm{d}x\\
\implies \bbox[5px,border:3px solid #AA2222]{y^2=k-\frac{x}{c}}\end{align}$$
With $k\in\mathbb{R}$.

Why there are two constants and what do they mean?
Firstly, $k$ determines where on the original curve the trajectory intersects. $c$ is determined by the original curve, and  will necessarily be in the final answer because different values of $c$ with result in different curvature at the same point. Have a fiddle on a  [Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/48xdyenmee).